# YouTube API 1.2.2 not properly working with YouTube latest version (10.49.59)

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have implemented YouTubePlayer api in my application. I am using CHROMELESS style and controlling YouTube Player with my own custom controls. Its working fine with lower version of YouTube (10.03.5 or 10.18.55)  but when I use latest version of YouTube and try to play video after resuming my screen it never plays video, instead YouTube stop working.

Can anyone please suggest me any solution which I can use and work with latest YouTube version.

Similar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431811/youtube-android-api-1-2-2-stop-working-after-onpause-with-newest-youtube-versio

Code:
1) onInitilize I check whether Video is watched or not.

```
@Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            Log.e(getLocalClassName() , "was not restored");
            ytPlayer = player;

            Log.e(getLocalClassName(), "Video Id-----" + videoId);
            checkAlreadyWatched(videoId);
        }else{
            Log.e(getLocalClassName(), "Restored...");
            ytPlayer = player;
            ytPlayer.play();
        }
    }
```

2) checkAlreadyWatched

```
public void checkAlreadyWatched(String videoCode){

            if (readPref.getIntValue(videoCode) != 0) {
                Log.e(getLocalClassName(), "Video Already Watched....");
                showError("Do you want to continue where you left?", ytPlayer, videoCode);

            } else {
                playVideo(ytPlayer, videoCode, 0);
            }
    }
```

3) playVideo

```
public void playVideo(YouTubePlayer player , String videoCode , int seek){


        player.loadVideo(videoCode, seek);
        player.play();

        player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);


        player.setPlaybackEventListener(this);
        player.setShowFullscreenButton(true);


        player.setOnFullscreenListener(new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFullscreen(boolean b) {
                Log.e(getLocalClassName(), "FullScreenListener----" + b);
                youTubeView.bringToFront();

                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        ytPlayer.play();
                    }
                }, 3000);

                isFullScreen = b;
                if (b) {
                    imgFullScreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_vidcontrol_fullscreen_on);
                    hideControls(); // hide my custom controls
                    hideUIElements(); // hide other views in Activity
                    if (android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                            Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rotate Screen and switch to Portrait mode..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    imgFullScreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_vidcontrol_fullscreen_off);
                    showControls();
                    showUIElements();
                }
            }
        });

        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoading() {
                hideControls();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdStarted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoStarted() {
                seekBar.setMax(ytPlayer.getDurationMillis());

                seekBar.setProgress(ytPlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis());
                if(!isFullScreen)
                    showControls();
                int seconds = (int) ((player.getDurationMillis() / 1000) % 60);
                int minutes = (int) ((player.getDurationMillis() / 1000) / 60);

            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoEnded() {
                Log.e(getLocalClassName(), "Video Ended");

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {
                hideControls();
                Log.e("YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason"  , errorReason.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

4) onResume --  When Activity is Resumed i check player for null and check if its paused then play the video.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(ytPlayer != null){
            if(isPaused){
                ytPlayer.play();
            }
        }
    }
```

On Resuming player starts playing if Youtube version is lower as I mentioned. But in Latest Version Video is never played , instead Youtube stops working.

Comment: Can you provide your current code implementation?

Comment: @ gRenzFries  I have added my current implementation.

Comment: Did you get rid of this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33931880/youtube-integration-in-android-does-not-work-in-lollipop

Comment: @RBhagwat - No I am still facing this error